# New tags differentiating [slick] questions for Slick 1.x and Slick 2.x

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

[Slick is a Scala persistence framework](http://slick.typesafe.com/) that recently came out with a [not totally backwards-compatible 2.0 release](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2014/01/21/slick-2.0.0-released.html).

Since my reputation [isn't sufficient for creating new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), I'm asking for the new tags on here.

Comment: Tags can't be created out of thin air. Give us links to a few questions it would be applicable to, and we may be able to put a new tag on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following:

- Created the tag [slick-2.0](/questions/tagged/slick-2.0)
- Suggested an excerpt and [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slick-2.0/info)
- Tagged [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528523/slick-2-0-returning-an-element-is-not-working-for-h2-database) with the version specific tag

Improving current questions including retagging can now take place by the followers of [slick](/questions/tagged/slick)

For the moment I don't see a reason to add a tag for slick 1.0 as that would require adding or retagging all questions currently in that tag which is not of much use. If there are pressing reasons to do otherwise, leave a comment here.

Comment: Basically any question that involves the 22-column inherent tuple restriction that's built into the Scala compiler. See [a question I raised earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19227864/1708136). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050184/1708136) actually explains the reason better.

Comment: Since most of those questions matching a search query of `[slick] 22` don't have solid answers, I guess a slick-1.0 tag wouldn't be of much use. I'll be tagging anything mentioning HLists with slick-2.0 though.

Comment: Although I suppose questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20735410/1708136) would benefit from a slick-1.0 tag.

Comment: You can ask user cvogt to either create it and/ot leave a comment here.